# Win 10 - Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake

Tags: python, qt

i'm trying to install PyQt5 (5.8.1) on Windows 10. The file was downloaded from RiverBank PyQt5 Download Windows source. When i run configure.py from Python 3.6 idle i got this Error:
Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: I tryed pip install pyqt5 from cmd as admin and have: Downloading/unpacking pyqt5. Downloading/unpacking sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5). Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for sip>=4.19.1 (from pyqt5)
Storing debug log for failure in ...\pip\pip.log

Comment: Any luck with this? I am having same issue on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0):

qmake is required for PyQt.

you have to install the Qt package from 
https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

This will automatically create qmake executable. 
You can add the qmake path to your windows path, incase the qmake is not added automatically.
your command to configure will be something like this,

```
    python configure.py --qmake {System_path}/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/qmake
```